# Some keys stop working, and it's not my keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, task-manager, keystrokes

The keys 1/2/3/4 stop working randomly.

It's not a keyboard problem, because if I change my keyboard, the problem persists.

The problem fixes spontaneously, or after I restart the PC.

It's always the same four keys.

I used a key-press monitoring software (Carnac) which shows that these keys *are* being registered at some level by the OS. There's just something blocking those key-presses at some point.
[image]

//

**UPDATE**

I can consistently fix the problem by opening `Task Manager`, and then forcing the *any* process to end (via pressing `End Task`). Yep! I can end the `Chrome` task/process, or even `Task Manager` *itself*, and the problem will immediately fix. Strange!

There's something about merely ending a process that is fixing the issue.

//

Comment: Make a bootable USB Key (likely Linux). Start with this and see if the keys work. This is about the 3rd time I have seen this question.

Comment: @John The keys will work if I do that because the problem always fixes when I restart the PC.  Also, sorry about that, but I've re-submitted this question because of novel and relevant information (I just bought a new keyboard today, so I was able to eliminate the hardware fault explanation). Next time I'll just edit the same question instead of reposting.

Comment: What software(s) are you using when the problem begins? Is the problem system-wide or limited to specific programs?

Comment: @music2myear One time I was browsing in Chrome. Another time I was playing Age of Empires 4. I haven't been able to isolate a common denominator.

Comment: Are you able to put in a temporary new disk , install an OS on the new disk and test with the new disk?

Comment: Is Chrome always running (even in background) when this happens? You wouldn't be using Internet Download Manager, by chance? Are you using a gaming keyboard that has special software for configuring hot-keys and macros (i.e. Logitech Gaming Software, Corsair iCue, etc...)?

Comment: @spaceman-spiff (1) Possibly yes on Chrome, but I don't remember. (2) Not using Internet Download Manager. (3) Yes, using a RedDragon K552 keyboard which has some inbuilt macros. But I haven't customized it at all or installed any software.

Comment: @John That's a really great idea in order to isolate if it's a non-HDD issue, but I don't have a new disk at the moment. I will keep it in mind if I get desperate, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an `AutoHotkey` script I was running. When I ensure it's closed, the problem resolves and doesn't come back. I'm not sure *where* in the script this is happening, but that is the root cause.